# Jquery functions overriding each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## Question:

I have 2 `jQuery` function one is a search function and the other is a function to only show column values of a certain type. The problem is if I select a column value with the second function and hide the other rows then try to search those rows it resets and searches all rows.

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nx30zqjd/1/)

## Code:

Here are the 2 functions:

### Search:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
      $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

### Column:

```
$(function() {
   $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').change(function(e) {
      let socket = $(this).val();
      $('tbody tr[data-socket]').show();
      if (socket.length) {
        $('tbody tr[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').hide();
      }
   });
   $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').trigger('change');
});
```

## Expected result:

I was thinking that the function could only apply to rows that aren't hidden but I'm not sure what the code for that would be.

## Update:

I saw the [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector and thought i could use `.not(:hidden)`

I also plan to add more functions in future so need it to be able to scale.

If you need any more information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah if you just hide the rows on your table, you definitely should use the :hidden selector to ensure you ignore those hidden rows

Comment: just not sure how to add it to the code i was thinking $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() { and $('tbody tr[data-socket]').show();? But not sure, and not sure how to add it

Comment: I know its just hiding the rows in column function but not sure for search can you tell from code above?

Comment: I think you should not just hide the rows. How do you know when the row is hidden because it doesn't match the option selected in CPUMenu or when it doesn't match the content of the search input ? This is problematic

Comment: I thought to hide the rows when a search or column function is executed and to unhide them when it is undone. Also to apply all functions to only currently shown rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix, but sorry won't scale well :

```
$(function() {
 $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').change(function(e) {
    let socket = $(this).val();
    $('tbody tr[data-socket]').removeClass('discarded').show(); /// <<<- here the trick
    if (socket.length) {
      $('tbody tr[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').addClass('discarded').hide(); /// <<<-- here as well
    }
 });
 $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').trigger('change');
});

$("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  $("#myTable tr:not(.discarded) td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work with search and column both not doing anything

Comment: just doing it now

Comment: oh figured out what i missed, see my edit. I need to hide hide/show the rows when you select an option in CPUMenu

Comment: I'm just finishing up the fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185679/discussion-between-codii-and-uskompuf).

Answer (score 2):

I dont really know what this would do but i think your search function should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
      if ($(this).parent.css("display") == "block") {
        $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)        
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: using that code when i search nothing happens but the selections from column function remain

Comment: sorry i can try to fix

Comment: the code now allows column to work again but search still does nothing.

Comment: what does it trigger if the search is successful ??

Comment: beacuse it triggers an int

Comment: That doesn't work, im not sure what it triggers the code i have in my post is all

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymgpcbd6/).

You could add, remove a class when you filter the rows by column and then search based on class usage.

Search Function:

```
     ...
     if($(this).parent().hasClass("filtered")){
           $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
     }
```

Column Function:

```
    ...
    if (socket.length) {
     $('tbody tr[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').hide();
     $('tbody tr[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').removeClass("filtered");
     $('tbody tr[data-socket="' + socket + '"]').addClass("filtered");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Just wondering how your approach differs from @Eliyah Sundström https://jsfiddle.net/nx30zqjd/2/ and if either one is "better".

Comment: Isn't very different, but I guess his is better.

Comment: No worries what I thought, but thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working code:

```
  $(function() {
    $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').change(function(e) {
      let socket = $(this).val();
      $('tbody tr[data-socket]').show();
      if (socket.length) {
            $('tbody tr[data-socket!="' + socket + '"]').hide();
          }
        });
        $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').trigger('change');
      });
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#mySearch").on("keyup", function() {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('select[name="CPUmenu"]').trigger('change');
      $("#myTable tr td:nth-child(1)").filter(function() {
      if ($(this).parent().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: In order to have a useful and comprehensible answer, you should explain what exactly you have done and why.